# Is there a software to easily deploy a db.json file?

Tags: web-apps, database, web-development, json, vue.js

Okay, so I recently created my first website in Vue, using json placeholder to mimic a database, as I only wanted to test the functionality. I successfully deployed my site to browser, and want to make it fully functional. Therefore, I have to make my database persistent, instead of just mimicking one like json placeholder.

Ideally what I would like to do is be able to simply upload my db.json file somewhere, and be able to post to and pull from it in the same way as I could with json placeholder. If anyone knows a site that will do this, that would be perfect. If not, could someone point me to a straightforward guide for setting it up?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would be interested in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/), a noSQL cloud database that stores data in a json-like format and allows you to use it like a regular JS object once retrieved. It's free for non high volume usage and you can see and interact with your database through a web interface.